# php timezone server summertime

Tags: php, date, timezone

I have a problem with the summertime in a server.

In the php.ini, I've added the following line:

```
date.timezone = "Europe/Lisbon"
```

And the server timestamp was great. But a few weeks agora, Lisbon has entered the summertime, and it's now GMT +1000.

The scripts running on the server are 1h delayed...

How can I fix this?

Thanks,

RL

Comment: Check the server's timezone setup. PHP date/time settings do not affect the OS configurations for this.

Comment: i don't have access to the server timezone, so I must use php.ini...

Comment: If those scripts are running as cron jobs, you'll have to adjust the server's time zone, or adjust the time the scripts are running at. PHP settings will NOT affect how/when cron runs a job.

Answer (score 1):

Use `UTC` as your timezone. It's basically GMT but without daylight savings.

Comment: but where in the server i use that? The issue is that i'm using just host.com, so i don't have access to the server settings.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of modifying the php.ini file.

Use
`date_default_timezone_set('timezone here');`

So try..

`date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Lisbon');`

Comment: where should i make that change? Not in php.ini?

Comment: You can make that change right in your php functions in your include files. But like you said, its off time, it seems its based off daylight saying. You'd had to edit a function to adjust according to daylight savings, which there are some ways you could do that. Here's an example http://php.bigresource.com/PHP-Daylight-Savings-Time-GMT-Alogorithm-H87oEoQs.html